# Gradient view not working programmatically with swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi guys please am trying to make a view inherit from a gradient UIView with a background to it but for one or two reasons its not inheriting. Here is my code:

```
// The gradient class I want to be inherited from
class GradientView: UIView {

    var gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupGradientView()
    }

    func setupGradientView(){
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.init(white:1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.locations = [0.8,1.0]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }

}

let headerHolder: GradientView = {
        let view = GradientView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

//Where i set up the views
  func setupViews() {
    view.addSubview(headerHolder)
            headerHolder.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            headerHolder.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            headerHolder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            headerHolder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call it inside

`override init(frame: CGRect)`

as `awakeFromNib` is not called in such init cases it's called when the view loaded from xib / stroryboard

**and** set the frame inside

```
override func layoutSubviews{}
```

as it's the place where the view gets it's correct `bounds`

//

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    var gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupGradientView()
    } 
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews() 
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func setupGradientView(){

        gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.locations = [0.8,1.0]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you override `awakeFromNib` method, but it's never called, because you create your `GradientView` programmatically. You see, `awakeFromNib` is called onle the view loaded from `Xib` or `Storyboard` file. Here is quote from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1402907-awakefromnib).

> The nib-loading infrastructure sends an awakeFromNib message to each object recreated from a nib archive, but only after all the objects in the archive have been loaded and initialized.

So if you want to create your view programmatically, you need to override `init(frame: CGRect)`.

The second problem is that in `setupGradientView` method you're using `self.bounds`, but your view bounds has not been computed yet, because `layout` was not called. You may setup gradient layer frame at `layoutSubviews` method.

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    var gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupGradientView()
    } 

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews() 
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
    }

    func setupGradientView() {
        let colorFrom = UIColor.white.cgColor
        let colorTo = UIColor.init(white:1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
        gradient.colors = [colorFrom, colorTo]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint.zero
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        gradient.locations = [0.8, 1.0]
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, because you created the `CAGradientLayer` directly, it doesn’t participate in UIKit’s layout system. You’re setting the gradient layer’s frame before the `GradientView` has been resized for the current device.

Instead of creating the gradient layer directly and making it a sublayer of the `GradientView`’s layer, tell `GradientLayer` that it’s own layer should be a `CAGradientLayer`:

```
class GradientView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }

    ...
}
```