# Background colour gradient doesn't cover the entire view Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, colors, background, gradient

After applying gradient to the view the result is as shown on the picture. Gradient colour (yelow part) doesn't stretch to the view bounds. Both yellow and red is is the same view. Can't figure out what's going on. And here's my code:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        //gradientLayer.frame = frame
        //gradientLayer.bounds = frame
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0
```

`colorOne` and `colorTwo` are defined elsewhere.

[image]
)

Anyone encounter the same problem?

[image: background gradient]

Comment: Your code is called before the parent view frame is updated (to the device size). That's why you have the issue. in viewDidLayoutSubViews, update the gradient frames.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937307/why-gradient-layer-in-uitableviewcell-not-cover-entire-frame https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348716/gradient-view-not-working-programmatically-with-swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269452/subview-frame-is-incorrect-when-creating-uicollectionviewcell etc.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the constraints in your `storyboard` not being applied until the `subviews` are laid out. At viewDidLoad() the view has a fixed size from the `storyboard`. If you move the code that sets the layer's frame to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` the constraints have been applied to yourView and it then has the correct frame. You can then set the layer's frame.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    gradientLayer.frame = yourView.bounds
}
```

Then it will fill the whole view.

Comment: `gradientLayer.frame = yourView.bounds` might be better.

Comment: Don't mention it!

Comment: Perhaps I spoke too soon... now it doesn't update to bounds when changing orientation.

Comment: Try:
override func layoutSubviews() {
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
}

Answer (score 0):

I spoke too soon... now it doesn't update to bounds when changing orientation (it's showing both horizontal and vertical gradient at the same time)
Any thoughts?

[image]